# Trigger and even when a nicedit toolbar button has finished executing or has been clicked

Tags: nicedit

I am trying to create and automatic preview mechanism for some content entered with "nicedit" editor. And I need to bind or be alerted when buttons like "bold", etc., have been clicked in order to update the preview panel. How do I hook into this functionality?

Comment: I ended up using the Google Mutations library to listen to changes made to the preview page, instead of listening on button events. Ended up being the better choice for me. https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Google Mutations library to listen to changes made to the preview page, instead of listening on button events. Ended up being the better choice for me.